# Windows Authentication in .net Core 2.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I've got a .net Core 2.1 MVC application that hosts an Angular 6 application.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.7.3.  I'm trying to set up Windows Authentication but am having issues.  I've followed the documentation and my Program.cs and Startup.cs are below:

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;
using System;

namespace CoreIV_Admin_Core
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            //.UseHttpSys(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
            //    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            //})
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
            })
            .UseNLog(); // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
}
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

namespace CoreIV_Admin_Core
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddMvc()
               .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseHttpContext();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"
                });
        });
    }
 }
}
```

If I uncomment the `.UseHttpSys` section in program.cs and press play in Visual Studio to debug, it almost immediately stops the debug session and the following error is in the Event log:

> "Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/myapp' with physical root
>   'C:\Users\me\myapp' created process with commandline 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
>   Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFCA6.tmp"' but failed to listen on
>   the given port '28353'".

If I try with `.UseHttpSys` commented out, the debugging works but I am unable to be properly authenticated.

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) carefully. You are mixing Kestrel stuff with HttpSys. You will never be able to authenticate with `HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` using Kestrel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Camilo thanks for your comment, it helped point me in the right direction.  I removed the UseHttpSys section from program.cs and added `.UseIISIntegration()`.  I also changed `services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` to `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` in my `startup.cs`.  I then ticked `Enable Windows Authentication` in the Debug section of the project properties and chose "IIS Express" for the Launch and it all worked.  I'm new to .net core with windows authentication so I don't know if I got it all set up exactly correct but it works and hopefully, this post helps point others in the right direction.